# SELECT query for three connected tables

Tags: mysql, database, select

My table structure looks like the following:

```
 subversions(
                id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
                version_id INT(10)
                name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
                PRIMARY KEY (id),
                FOREIGN KEY (version_id) REFERENCES versions(id)
            );
/*      ^
    Many|
       To
        | Many
        v
*/
users(
    id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
    password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
```

with junction table

```
subversions_users_conjuction(
    id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    subversion_id VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
    user_id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (subversion_id) REFERENCES subversions(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)    
);
```

My problem is designing query for selecting all users from "users" are **not in**
subversions_users_conjuction **with subversion_id = specificID** and without getting those who are

So something like the following:

```
//Query for all other users
$res2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT i.id, i.username FROM users AS i
                    NOT IN 
                    SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.username FROM users AS u
                    INNER JOIN subversion_user ON u.id = subversion_user.user_id
                    WHERE subversion_user.subversion_id = '$subversionID'");
```

but , this one doesn't work
SQL Error says:

```
MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT IN 
                        SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.username FROM users AS u
                        INNER JOI' at line 2
```

Comment: How about `user_id` and `subversion_id` instead of just the two different plain `id`s in your original declaration?

Comment: I did those queries in many different forms , this one is just for basic concept of what I was using, but it doesnt work

Comment: wow.  I just found http://sqlfiddle.com/  Let me see if I can reproduce (or you can do the same....) hint, hint!

Comment: Can you explain the subversions table?  What does it store and why?  (Use case?).  (Frankly I'm lost in all the obtuse id names and what they represent.  )

Comment: it stores its ID, and its Name..the foreign key to version_id is now irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem in the form of this query:

```
//Query for all other users
    $res2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT id, username FROM users 
                         WHERE id  NOT IN ( 
                                SELECT DISTINCT u.id  FROM users AS u
                                INNER JOIN subversion_user ON u.id = subversion_user.user_id
                                WHERE subversion_user.subversion_id = '$subversionID' 
                            )");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three tables, and you want to join them.  Additionally you want to find entries that are 'missing' from a normal inner join.  In this case you want an outer join.  (Unfortunately mySQL doesn't include a FULL OUTER JOIN)

[My SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ae8a/2)

My test code:

```
CREATE TABLE subversion
(
   id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO subversion (name) VALUES ('Terror');
INSERT INTO subversion (name) VALUES ('Mayhem');
INSERT INTO subversion (name) VALUES ('Bribery');
INSERT INTO subversion (name) VALUES ('Eating Ice Cream');
INSERT INTO subversion (name) VALUES ('Unrest');
INSERT INTO subversion (name) VALUES ('Infiltration');

CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
    password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO users (name, password) VALUES
('Adam', '12345'),('Bill', '78903'), ('Chandra', '56565'),
('David', '34543'), ('Edwina', 'abcde'), ('Faheem', 'jklab'), ('George', 'vfghn'), ('Hank', '2ws3e') ;

CREATE TABLE subversions_users_conjuction(
    id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    subversion_id INT(10) NOT NULL, 
    user_id INT(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (subversion_id) REFERENCES subversion(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)    
);

INSERT INTO subversions_users_conjuction (user_id, subversion_id) VALUES
(1,1), (2,2), (3,1), (4,4), (5,5);
```

My LEFT OUTER query

```
SELECT * FROM 
users LEFT OUTER JOIN subversions_users_conjuction 
ON users.id = subversions_users_conjuction.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN subversion ON subversion.id = subversions_users_conjuction.subversion_id 
WHERE subversion_id IS NULL;
```

Results:

```
| id |   name | password |     id | subversion_id | user_id |     id |   name |
|----|--------|----------|--------|---------------|---------|--------|--------|
|  6 | Faheem |    jklab | (null) |        (null) |  (null) | (null) | (null) |
|  7 | George |    vfghn | (null) |        (null) |  (null) | (null) | (null) |
|  8 |   Hank |    2ws3e | (null) |        (null) |  (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

Things I learned here:

- [Database ID naming convention](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114728/why-is-naming-a-tables-primary-key-column-id-considered-bad-practice)
- INNER / OUTER JOINs
- IS NULL / IS NOT NULL operators
- sqlfiddle.com

Comment: I dont think we understood each other, i edted my question with my newest query try, so maybe now is more clear what I want